# How to join two database table in sql query for cakephp 3.6.7

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

can anyone tell me to join two tables from database

**my php query is :**

```
SELECT * FROM `users`  INNER JOIN registration ON users.id=registration.id WHERE users.id='7'
```

can anyone convert to **Cakaphp 3.6.7**

thanks & regards,
Darshan

Comment: Stackoverflow ist not a code writing service. Read the documentation. book.cakephp.org

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use plural name for your model Registration. It should be Registrations.

You can use association for the same in Cakephp.
First define your association in /src/Model/Table/UsersTable.php file.

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasOne('Registrations')->setJoinType('INNER');;
    }
}
```

Then query like this

```
$this->Users->find('all')->contain('Registrations')->where(['Users.id => 7]);
```

Reference: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html